# Can I convert minutes to hours without a double?

Tags: java

I want calculate distance of a car traveling in KM. I need to calculate the distance, speed and time with integer. Can I do that without a double?

```
System.out.println("Please enter the speed of the first train: "); 
int speed1 = scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("Please enter the travel time (minutes) of the first train: ");
int time1 = scan.nextInt();
final int DISTANCE_FIRST_TRAIN = (speed1*time1) / 60;
```

Comment: Sure, but you'll get an imprecise result. Why do you want that?

Comment: Hint: if you decide to calculate the *metres* travelled instead of *kilometres* then the effect of the rounding will be significantly smaller. So `speed * time1 * 1000L / 60` for example, as the number of metres travelled...

Comment: Yes, you can but I suggest using Double for precise results

Comment: `double` too will get you an imprecise result, but only much less imprecise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way based on a slight modification of your code. This doesn't really convert minutes to hours but it uses `int` manipulation to convert the raw product to a fairly accurate distance. I am generating `speed` and `time` values randomly and doing it 10 times to show the comparison between a double answer and an int answer.  The `int` version is almost identical to the double version at two decimal places.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    int speed1 = r.nextInt(100) + 50;
    int time1 = r.nextInt(50) + 200;

    double dist = (double) speed1 * time1 / 60.;
    int time_x_speed = time1 * speed1;
    int distanceWhole = time_x_speed / 60;
    int distanceFraction = time_x_speed % 60 * 100 / 60;
    String result = distanceWhole + (distanceFraction <= 9 ?".0" : ".")  + distanceFraction;
    System.out.printf(
            "Distance: using double = %.2f   using ints = %s%n", dist,
            result);

}
```

prints

```
Distance: using double = 547.55   using ints = 547.55
Distance: using double = 260.33   using ints = 260.33
Distance: using double = 282.82   using ints = 282.81
Distance: using double = 226.67   using ints = 226.66
Distance: using double = 401.20   using ints = 401.20
Distance: using double = 247.07   using ints = 247.06
Distance: using double = 526.70   using ints = 526.70
Distance: using double = 326.67   using ints = 326.66
Distance: using double = 294.80   using ints = 294.80
Distance: using double = 298.80   using ints = 298.80
```

Answer (score 0):

> can i convert minutes to hours without a double?

```
long hours = Duration.ofMinutes( x ).toHours() ;
```

But I doubt that is what you truly want for your particular calculation scenario.